# What chance do the Republicans have of passing their recently proposed legislation without having the Senate or the presidency?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives

The new Republican majority in the House of Representatives announced a set of bills concerning budget, taxing, and abortion, in terms and contents which seem to be red-line for Democrats.

Even if they pass each of these bills in the House, which I don't doubt they can, and considering the difficulty the previous Senate democratic 50-seat majority faced in order to pass their legislation, such as the "For the people act" (due in major part to the filibuster), is there any chance that the republican 49-seat minority pass these bills into law ?

Comment: I'm talking about these bills, the legislation the house republicans are proposing - see Section 5 of this resolution for examples https://rules.house.gov/sites/republicans.rules118.house.gov/files/BILLS-118hresPIH-118th-rules-of-the-house-of-reps-V3.pdf

Comment: Great! If you're uncomfortable with the edit to the title feel free to edit further (or roll back). Sometimes folks can get hung up on "unclear what you are asking" or post an answer to the title only and ignore the body of the text (and comments).

Comment: @uhoh I was thinking more broadly of any "very-republican" legislation, not the particular set of bills they recently proposed, but this version is certainly better than the former one. And I realize the body of the question doesn't make that clear either...

Answer (score 4):

Unless they are passing something that Democrats and Biden agree on or they get them to agree on as part of a deal for other items it will be impossible. In order for any bill to pass and become law it needs to be passed by both chambers and signed by the president.

If the bill does pass both chambers but is vetoed by the president it would require a two thirds vote in both chambers to pass it and they can't get that in either chamber on their own.

Answer (score 2):

At some point, the House and Senate are going to need to agree to raise the debt ceiling and to pass a new budget (to avoid a government shutdown). This gives the House a fair amount of leverage; they could (say) refuse to pass a budget that doesn't satisfy at least some of their priorities.

Comment: That is only one of the issues that they are trying to get passed and that need doesn't impact other bills they want.

Comment: In theory, they could hold the budget hostage for any reason, though it is more likely that they'll do so for budget-related things.

Comment: Sure, but the budget isn't the only thing on their agenda

Comment: They could certainly say "we'll only raise the debt ceiling in a bill that also restricts abortion and does 5 other things we want." Unlikely but very much possible.

Comment: I don't see how this can happen unless you get 213 (or 214 after the missing seat is filled) Republican's to agree that the country should be shut down for a different bill. I find it hard to believe that shutting down the government and the bad press it would cause would be supported by that many of them.

Comment: @alphabet I hope they actually do that, so the whole system of made-up rules comes crashing down and we see what actually matters. I don't think they'll default on T-bills, I think they'll just start ignoring rules that nobody really cares about, to get the payments through.  I'll bring popcorn.

Comment: @JoeW Biden is the president, so they'll just spin it as "Biden can't govern". It doesn't have to be congruent with reality.

Comment: @user253751 They can spin it however they want, but that doesn't mean that the voters have to believe what they say.

Comment: @JoeW but they *will* believe "Biden can't govern". We've seen plenty of this already.

Comment: @user253751 This is a debate that is irrelevant to the question as there is no need to get into that fine of a detail about what may or may not happen if the house holds the budget hostage. My original comment was just pointing out that there was plenty on their agenda that had nothing to do with the budget.

Comment: I kinda agree, to my recollection democrats were kinda taking the budget hostage to not fund trump's wall, so it's not exactly passing their ideas and rather stonewalling others' ideas, but reps could do it the other way, for example by cutting the IRS budget like they want to. Also the december omnibus was kinda forcing a lot of things over the pretext of avoiding a shutdown - although a trifecta is a very different context obviously.

Comment: @Gouvernathor Your recollection disagrees with the opinion of most Americans at the time, and with most historians. The budget passed by Congress did not provide all of the monies Trump had asked for in his budget request for building his wall. It's Congress, not the President, that sets the budget. The President issues a request, not a demand. Trump claimed "I am proud to shut down the government for border security," and he did.

Comment: @Gouvernathor As a general rule, the party that the majority of people perceive to be mostly responsible for a shutdown (this has happened multiple times), or heaven forbid, a default (this hasn't happened yet) loses in the next election.